# how to avoid count with empty records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When i try to get count of values from a column in my sql table it returns records of all values of that column but what i need that if there are empty records in column then count should not get empty records but should count other records.
here is my query to count the values of column

```
SELECT COUNT( dt_UserTTrainingDate2) as a FROM ref_CourseRegistration_Users
```

is there a way ?

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data.  Assuming that "empty" means `NULL`, then you have the right construct.  Given that the field seems to be a date, what else could "empty" mean?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'empty' records.  The query you show will only count the non-NULL values in `dt_UserTTrainingDate2`, which sounds more or less like what you want — unless you've done something idiotic like stored the date in a CHAR field and used blanks instead of NULL to indicate the absence of a date.

Comment: in my case empty not mean null so it means empty string is stored in column not null value

Comment: Well, if you make idiotic design decisions, you'll have to write harder SQL to compensate for your idiocy.  If your column is to store dates, it should be the DATE type; it should NOT be a string type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this construct:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(dt_UserTTrainingDate2,'')) as a 
FROM ref_CourseRegistration_Users
```

It uses [NULLIF()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) function which compares 2 values and returns NULL if they're equal. And in this case resulting NULL will not be included into count

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the comments, your `dt_UserTTrainingDate2` column is not a DATE type but rather some sort of string type.  This is bad database design; use the built-in types.

Given that it is a string, you'll have to work harder in your SQL, all the time.  It really is making a rod for your own back, using the wrong type, but that's your problem, not ours.

```
SELECT COUNT(dt_UserTTrainingDate2) AS a
  FROM ref_CourseRegistration_Users
 WHERE dt_UserTTrainingDate2 != ' ';
```

Count the rows where the date string is not blank.  It also ignores any rows that do have a NULL value.

Moral: use DATE type to store dates.